# AngularJS datatables refresh after adding new object

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I'm trying to add new user like this :

```
$scope.users = UserService.query();

UserService.save({}, newUser, function (data) {
    $scope.users.push(data);
});
```

- It's adding to server (F5 creates wanting result),
- checking with `console.log($scope.users)` its also added here.

but that does not change the display

**otherwise** this works well:

```
UserService.delete({ id: userId }, function (data) {
    ...
    $scope.homeworks.splice(index, 1);
    ...
});
```

How can i refresh table after array change ?

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried `$scope.$evalAsync` and `$q`

**UPDATE 2**

I am using [The Angular Way](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay), trying this :  [Changing data with the Angular way](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWayDataChange)

Html:

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>{{user.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.Surname}}</td>
            <td>{{user.Address}}</td>
            ...
            ...
            ...
            <td class="center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" ng-click="edituser(user.Id)">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" ng-click="deleteuser(user.Id)">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE 3:**

I solved:

I try to call this function from modal, if I call inside of page its work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved:

I try to call this function from **modal**, if I call inside of page its work.

Comment: how did you refresh datatable

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$scope.$apply()` after you pushing user data

Comment: Its returning error always, is that normal ? https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest